# KDB looping over inputs for a dyadic function

Tags: function, parameters, kdb

I have a function `f[x;y]` that outputs a table, and I want to comma-join these tables across a list of x's and y's.  Any nifty way I could do something like

```
(,/)f each xList each yList
```

which concatenates the tables produced by `f[x1;y1],f[x1;y2],...,f[x2;y1],f[x2;y2],...etc`?

If I changed f to monadic that took in a single tuple, I would do something like `(,/)f each xList cross yList`.  However, I would like to keep the function dyadic if possible.

Comment: This looks the same as your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253131/kdb-apply-dyadic-function-across-two-lists?rq=1

Comment: You know what...I was just realizing that. I forgot that I had asked this same question...and the recipe in that response still works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this should work. if producing keyed tables you'll want to (upsert/)

```
raze{raze{f[x;y] }[;x] each y }[;xList] each yList
```

edit:
the referenced solution in comments is cleaner

```
raze F ./: xList cross yList
```